# ElectronJS React custom menu Event is not defined

Tags: reactjs, events, electron

Hi I'm using ElectronJS with React trying to fire off an event whenever I click the save button on the menu in electorn js. I'm trying to listen to the event within a component, however on click of the menu item I get this error;

```
Uncaught Exception:
ReferenceError: Event is not defined
    at click (/private/Apps/hosts/src/electron-starter.js:38:21)
```

This is my code;

```
const template = [
    {
        label: 'File',
        submenu: [
            {
                label: 'Save', accelerator: 'Cmd+S',
                click() {
                    console.log('send event');
                    new Event('save-hosts-file');
                }
            },
        ]
    },
];
```

and in my component;

```
componentDidMount() {

        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener('save-hosts-file', function (e) { console.log('save file');}, false)
    }
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const template = [
    {
        label: 'File',
        submenu: [
            {
                label: 'Save', accelerator: 'Cmd+S',
                click() {
                    mainWindow.webContents.send('save-hosts-file');
                }
            },
        ]
    },
];

componentDidMount() {
  ipcMain.on('save-hosts-file', (event) => {
     console.log('save file');
   });
 }
```

there are 2 things you should remember:

1) sending event from electron to react and receiving in react

sending event from electron to react -- **mainWindow.webContents.send**
receiving event in react sent from electron -- **ipcRenderer.on**

2) sending event from react to electron and receiving in electron

sending event from react to electron -- **ipcRenderer.send**
receiving event in electron sent from react -- **ipcMain.on**

Comment: it's `ipcRenderer` on react side (renderer process)

Comment: @pergy My bad. Thanks. :)